# Cant center and fit text and divs properly

Tags: css, html, text, center

Hey I am trying to center my text inside a div and at the same time fit three divs inside my content area but somehow that isn't working out...

HTML

```
            <div id="content">
        <div class="latest">
            <p>Gentlemen, these are my latest works</p>
        </div>
        <div id="works">
            <div class="one"> 
                <a href="myworks.html" class="title">Lineage 3 Online</a>
                <div class="prev1"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="two"> 
                <a href="myworks.html" class="title">Lineage 3 Online</a>
                <div class="prev2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="three"> 
                <a href="myworks.html" class="title">Lineage 3 Online</a>
                <div class="prev2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
    div#content {
width: 1000px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
    }

    div.latest {
text-align: center;
font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #777;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 5px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 18px;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
border-bottom: 2px solid #DADADA;
    }

    div#works {
margin-top: 8px;
border-top: 2px solid #DADADA;
    }

    /*************************************/

    div.one {
float: left;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
margin-top: 10px;
border: 1px dotted #333;

    }

    div.two {
    width: 300px;
height: 300px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border: 1px dotted #333;
    }

    div.three {
float: right;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
margin-top: 300px;
border: 1px dotted #333;
    }


    a.title {
color: #333;
font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: center;
letter-spacing: 3px;
line-height: 3;
border: 1px solid #000;

    }


    div.prev1 {
background-image: url(images/prev1.jpg);
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
border: 2px solid #FFF;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
    }
```

I would also like to add that I am fairly new to HTML5 and CSS so sorry if this question sounds stupid.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have an extra closing `</div>` tag on each of your divs that are direct children of the `#works` div.

Once you remove those extraneous closing tags, to center the text, add `text-align:center` to the `div#works` css:

```
div#works {
    margin-top: 8px;
    border-top: 2px solid #DADADA;

    /* add this */
    text-align: center;
}
```

The children of the `#works` div will inherit it's text-align property.

Your divs are not aligning properly because you don't have the middle one floated, and the third one has a margin-top of 300px, while the other two have a margin-top of 10px.

Instead of creating new rules for each of these elements, since they are all children of the `#works` div you can create a more general rule, selecting only the children of the `#works` div:

```
#works > div {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px dotted #333;
}
```

In this case, the `>` selector is selecting only the direct children of the `#works` div.

http://jsfiddle.net/jfUxA/3/

Just a recommendation as well: you don't need to prefix your id selectors with the element name. Especially since id's are only supposed to appear once on a page, further classifying your selector with the element is redundant.

Comment: Oh! Great! Thanks a lot! you said I don't have the middle one floated, but what would I need to write to have all three divs in there instead of only the two? I fixed the top margin of the third one, however it's still below and not next to the other ones! I figured out the "margin-right: auto;" on the second div seems to cause the third div being below instead of beside it. However I need it center the second div, no?

Comment: it could be because the container div is not large enough to accommodate for the children divs, since they all have an absolute width of 300px. To ensure that the three will fit inside their container, you could change the width of the children to 33.333%, so each takes up 1/3 of its parent.

Setting the margin on the sides to auto only centers an individual element within a parent, and won't really help you with basic structure if there should be divs to the left and right as well.